# about Google fonts after Facebook redirects

Tags: php, css, facebook, fonts, google-fonts

I am using uploaded google fonts on my website. When I open url on browsers it works but when I share it on facebook . It works on desktops but it doesnt work on mobilephones

redirect: https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http://website

```
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Grand Hotel';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Grand Hotel'), local('GrandHotel-Regular'), url(../fonts/grandhotel-regular.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Grand Hotel';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Grand Hotel'), local('GrandHotel-Regular'), url(../fonts/grandhotel-regular-II.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

**I couldnt find the issue. What should I do?**

Comment: did you try @import url(https:// ?

Comment: Yes. The same. Nothing changed